# what does the location of the SDK file mean?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios-frameworks

*ios noob here, so basic question*

In the file tree shown below: Bolts.framework, Parse.framework, and ParseFacebookUtils.framework are under the main project code folder "Tinder", but the other frameworks (that I added by going to Build Phases menu) are under the root Tinder folder.

What does it mean to have different .framework files in different locations? Does it matter? (for ex: FacebookSDK.framework is not at the same folder location as Bolts.framework - does it matter?)

[image: Project File Tree]

Comment: Is your code working? Is it still working if you move the frameworks location? Then no, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not matter where they are saved. What I do though is right click root (in your case tinder) and create a new group called frameworks. I then drag parse and bolts into it. Making sure the folder is still highlighted I then add all other dependencies in the normal way and they go in the group also. It just keeps it clean as you can minimise the folder and loose the eyesore that is the list of dependencies.

Hope this helps.

Cheers.

Comment: so Xcode pulls in the frameworks irrespective of ANYWHERE they are in the folder structure?

Comment: Yes, remember, when your code is compiled it is changed to binaries so the folder structure is not relevant. I am sure there are exceptions but the location of frameworks can be a folder inside a folder inside a folder if you so wish. ( untested by the way ;))

Comment: ok got it. I am coming from the world of Java (Android) where the relative location of class files and frameworks/libraries do matter, so I guess that's why i had this question. I will mark your answer as the right answer, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Thanks. I am however not sure at this point what happens when you save it in one location then move it about. I will need to try it out!